# Como instalar versão 6.10.3 do nodejs sem ser pelo terminal

Tags: node.js, npm

Como consigo instalar a versão 6.10.3 do nodejs no ubuntu ? Quando faço as instalação pela terminal (sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs) ele instala sempre a versão 4.7.2. 
Existe outra forma de instalar sem ser pelo terminal ?
Grato
Flávio

Comment: Podes tentar a instalação manual do nodeJS .
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Encontrei a solução neste post;

Comment: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/324 - Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os repositórios estão desatualizados, eles explicam que se deve usar o curl [aqui](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions). Aí é baixar o pacote direto deles e mandar instalar.

Você tem duas outras opções: compilar o código fonte ([instruções no site do node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-nodejs-on-supported-platforms)) ou baixar os binários direto do site e incluir no seu PATH.

Comment: Olá Daniel, fiz a instalação utilizando o curl que você enviou, porém quando ele vai baixar os pacotes, acontece o seguinte erro:

Comment: E: Falhou o download de alguns ficheiros de índice. Foram ignorados ou os antigos foram usados em seu lugar.
Error executing command, exiting

Comment: Sabe como resolver este problema?

Comment: Verifica se o arquivo de setup está chegando, roda o curl sem o ``-sL``, só com ``-L`` e vê se tá chegando. Essa url deles tem um x no lugar do final da versão, então não sei se é pra colocar a versão desejada ou se com o x ele traz a mais nova.